# Covert Channel Bandwidth

Tags: malware

I have designed a covert channel using ICMP protocol by making use of the data field when sending pings. I am trying now to analyize the bandwith of this channel but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a security question, but a networking one. Have you looked at wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

Let x be the maximum bandwidth possible on the network using the protocall without beeing detected (using the whole bandwidth of a network just for ICMP isn't really covert, is it?). Calculate y=(size usable for data in a packet)/(whole size of a packet). (Bandwidth of the covert channel) = x*y.